# Repeated PTS/DTS in a PES header

Tags: h.264, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

When processing an MPEG-2 Transport Stream into an elementary stream and 2 PES Headers are encountered in a row with the same PTS/DTS how should these be handled in regard to storing timing meta data?

Should the duplicate be ignored? If so does the following packet data just get appended to the prior frame?

For example https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/gear1/fileSequence2.ts

At packet 1966 and 1967 appear to be the same PES Header repeated, does this mean the following data belongs to the same frame?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
PES Header pkt:1966 frame 87 PTS 2110500 DTS 2110500 size 157 payload true
[227 112 183 53 53 231 47 203 210 247 30 0 109 221 26 233 159 237 247 193 210 
244 14 4 144 228 183 130 11 101 92 224 17 206 134 150 185 31 234 80 56 12 149 0 
56 220 227 48 223 177 225 221 222 208 126 22 88 230 65 169 58 153 120 97 74 105 
244 154 65 63 176 2 211 42 246 187 87 208 196 37 206 183 249 224 5 22 57 85 64 
221 241 227 189 59 163 212 241 123 219 115 60 79 1 210 204 229 194 228 42 4 96 
82 16 18 2 84 29 2 64 168 167 200 237 129 180 76 197 134 253 216 111 143 32 17 
1 136 8 208 35 8 120 77 149 33 191 223 12 186 95 0 78 132 252 159 147 224 230]
PES Header pkt:1967 frame 88 PTS 2110500 DTS 2110500 size 157 payload true
PTS repeated from last frame
DTS repeated from last frame
[0 0 1 9 80 0 0 1 6 1 7 0 0 174 0 0 3 0 4 128 0 0 1 6 4 41 181 0 49 71 65 57 52 
3 202 255 252 194 233 250 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 250 0 0 
250 0 0 250 0 0 255 128 0 0 1 1 158 121 100 15 192 137 20 128 155 237 91 194 65  
38 179 35 208 112 71 39 128 168 189 178 9 239 222 1 187 200 123 244 218 76 99 
79 102 191 216 209 241 222 221 190 177 41 191 92 245 243 236 90 81 61 154 86 97 
238 175 111 191 191 239 240 7 172 120 72 72 72 74 0 195 61 36 66 60 239 41 122 
35 179 252 1 204]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a large elementary stream frame (e.g. MPEG video I frame) divided into two PES packets.

Also consider this: [MPEG-TS file audio and video frame length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677652/mpeg-ts-file-audio-and-video-frame-length)

I think we should process TS stream by the timing information in the ES frame not by PTS/DTS.

Comment: It looks like the second packet includes the start of a new NAL, so maybe that has some relevance? I'll add some sample data to the original question

Comment: Also note here the issue is with the 2 PES Headers, not data split into 2 PES packets. Where is the timing info in the ES?